# Deploy ASP.NET Core to IIS UI and API into seperated websites

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, axios

Having a solution that contains UI and API.

**UI**

Is a `ASP.NET Core MVC` project that contains just a `HomeController` and `Index` view which loads in a `VueJS` app.

**API**

Is a `ASP.NET Core Web API` to feed the VueJS app using Windows Authentication.

**Deployment**

- Current Setup ( 1 IIS Website )

We have one origin ( https://example.com ) where the API is accessed by https://exampel.com/api

- New setup ( 2 IIS Websites )

We have 2 origins ( https://app.example.com ) for the `UI` and ( https://api.example.com ) for the `API`.

For the new setup we need to implement CORS ( Cross Origin ) to allow the other website to use the API. But therefore we need to enable the anonymous authentication for the `OPTIONS` preflight requests.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0) That should help.

Comment: @aguafrommars I did all of that but to make it work I needed to set the Anonymous authentication to true to allow the OPTIONS reguests from the CORS. The question is to make it secure or if there is another solution to disable anonymous auth but have CORS working

Comment: You mean on IIS ? Or using ASP.Net Core Authentication and Authorization middlewares ?

Comment: There’s no way to avoid the need to allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests. The CORS protocol requires it. More specifically, the CORS protocol requires browsers to omit all credentials from the CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it using a custom middleware for authentication:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    // Check if the request is a PREFLIGHT => OPTIONS request
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        await _next(context);
        return;
    }

    await context.ChallengeAsync("Windows");
}
```

And in startup adding in the beginning of the pipeline:

```
app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
```